# Writing to memory-mapped IO. How long does the value need to be stable in order to be seen by IO?

Tags: c++, arm, fpga, memory-mapping, zynq

I have a memory-mapped IO element in my FPGA (to be precise, an AXI GPIO element, which basically maps an AXI Memory-Mapped interface to a set of pins), which is connected and mapped to an ARM processor's address space by the GP0 master port. Both the FPGA and the ARM processor is part of a ZYNQ7000 family device. When I write to the address of the element, where should I look for documentation, or what is the general mechanism, to ensure that the circuit 'sees' this write? Let's assume that I have this sequence of writes to `volatile` memory-mapped variable `port`

```
port = 0;
port = 1;
```

Then how can I ensure that for one cycle of 10ns, the clocked process (VHDL, if that's of any relevance) sees the `0`, and for a later cycle, the clocked process sees a `1`? Ideally, it would be for *the next* cycle, if that's possible. For a first approach, I would simply wait for long enough cpu cycles (using the cycle counter). But that looks like a rather "brutal" way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

For MMIO in general: there is no "how long" for a write to be seen. If you do a write, it will go out to the bus. If you do another write, it will go out to the bus afterwards. (Assuming a non-caching, non-write-combining mapping for the MMIO range). If the device at the other end of the bus takes some time to deal with a write, then that will usually be dealt with by polling the device.

I don't fully understand your specific case, but since you say it acts like a GPIO peripheral, I'll assume that it's very simple and that the FPGA side doesn't see the writes as events on the bus, it just sees the "GPIO lines" change state. Given that, you have a few options:

1. Do nothing. The two writes should hit the GPIO peripheral separated by at least one bus cycle, and if that's good enough (i.e. the GPIO doesn't require any hold time, and one bus cycle is long enough), then it's good enough.
2. Insert a read of the port in between the two writes. That should add an extra bus turnaround.
3. Just wait, like you suggested in your question. It's a perfectly normal thing to do when dealing with hardware, and 10ns isn't exactly a long time.

Comment: Thanks. The TRM says "A write to strongly ordered memory can complete only when it reaches the peripheral or memory component accessed by the write.". I think that's the first approach you listed. So I will try this first. Since the bus as appropriate handshake signals for data arrival, that should work out fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is another problem not mentioned in the previous answer. Inserting the read before write is not enough, especially if the location is shadowed. In this case it is possible that two consecutive writes can possible reach the destination out of order. That is the reason why ARM cores have special barrier instructions.

> Ideally, it would be for the next cycle

You cant do such assumptions. You need yo analyse the particular case and choose the proper method

Comment: WOW, ok. I thought that the strongly ordered memory region attribute prevents out of order writes?

Comment: As I wrote - you need to consider a particular core bus configuration, and peripheral. There is no "magic" general answer.

Comment: The ARM cores I've read about allow different memory semantics to be applied to different regions of address space, and would not require memory barriers in order to ensure sequencing of I/O operations relative to each other.  From a hardware standpoint, memory barriers would only be required in cases where e.g. an I/O operation on one bus might switch power to a bank of memory accessed on another bus.

Answer (score 0):

On almost any microcontroller which has an "external memory bus" peripheral, that peripheral will automatically stall any CPU read requests until data is available, and will either stall any CPU write requests until they are complete, or else stall any operation which follows a write request until that request is complete.  Note that operations on the external bus may only be sequenced relative to each other, and not with respect to other memory or devices within the microcontroller.  For example, if there is a memory-mapped peripheral at address 0xABCD1234, and code writes a 1 to GPIO pin A0, then writes to that peripheral, and then writes a 1 to GPIO pin A1, the effects of the peripheral write may occur before the write to A0, or after the write to A1, or between the two operations on the I/O ports.  Use of memory-barrier instructions may help to ensure sequencing, but there's really no substitute for reading data sheets.  A memory barrier on the ARM might guarantee that an external bus write will complete before an instruction which sets an I/O port, but if the external hardware takes two cycles to perform an action in response to the bus write (not terribly unusual) the operation on the I/O port might still happen first.

Comment: NO. It is the truth only when you consider the simplest ones.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: On what sorts of common microcontrollers would a part of the address space configured for I/O usage (bypassing any caching that may exist) not behave as described, and how would they differ?  The controllers I've looked at all sequence I/O operations on the same bus relative to each other, and might overlap writes with I/O operations on independent buses but will block on reads.  Portions of address space configured as memory may behave differently, but presumably a programmer who wants something to behave as I/O would configure it as such.